# BackgroundWorker not running

Tags: .net, vb.net, backgroundworker

**Program Logic**

I'm making a simple signature based malware scanner that loads the file locations from a file. For each line in the file, it will try to get the md5 hash. Each line in the file is the absolute file location.

For for displaying the progress, I'm using a progressbar and background worker.

**Problem**

The background worker is not running at all. No matter what I do and how many times I call worker run asyn, it doesn't seem to run.

**Code: For toggle button**

```
Private Sub btnToggleScan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnToggleScan.Click
    If isScanning = True Then
        ' if scanning, stop scanning
        txtStatus.Text = "Status: Idle..."
        btnToggleScan.Image = Image.FromFile("res/malware_scanner/rocket.png")
        If bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then
            Try
                bgWorker_Scanner.CancelAsync()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End If
        isScanning = False
    Else
        ' if not scanning, start scanning
        txtStatus.Text = "Status: Scanning..."
        btnToggleScan.Image = Image.FromFile("res/malware_scanner/loading_dark.gif")
        If bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then
            Try
                bgWorker_Scanner.RunWorkerAsync()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Me.Close()
            End Try
        End If
        txtCalmDown.Text = "Feel free to do other work!"
        isScanning = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Code: For background worker**

```
Private Sub bgWorker_Scanner_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker_Scanner.DoWork
        ' storage declares
        Dim temp_hash_values As New List(Of String)() ' store malware hash per malware hash file
        Dim hashFile_lineParts As String() ' store parts of packed/unpacked hash
        Dim se_queryfile_hashes As New List(Of String)() ' store file hashes of search index query

        ' file operating declares
        Dim file_bytes() As Byte
        Dim file_bytes_size As Integer
        Dim lineInFile As String
        Dim lineBytes() As Byte
        Dim lineBytes_size As Integer
        Dim totalRead_size As Integer

        ' declare file reader
        Dim reader As StreamReader

        ' if quickscan, then get hash list
        If scanType = "Quick" Then
            Dim md5hash As String
            reader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(Application.StartupPath & "/data/win_searchIndex_results.list")
            ' get file bytes
            file_bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "/data/win_searchIndex_results.list")
            ' get size of file bytes in integer
            file_bytes_size = file_bytes.Length
            Do
                lineInFile = reader.ReadLine
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lineInFile) Then
                    ' get line bytes
                    lineBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lineInFile)
                    ' get line bytes size in integer
                    lineBytes_size = lineBytes.Length
                    ' add line bytes size to total size read
                    totalRead_size += lineBytes_size
                    Try
                        md5hash = Hasher.Getmd5(lineInFile)
                        se_queryfile_hashes.Add(md5hash.ToString)
                        ' testing
                        ' Dim temp As String = totalRead_size.ToString & " \ " & file_bytes_size.ToString
                        ' MsgBox(md5hash.ToString)
                    Catch ex As Exception : End Try
                End If
                bgWorker_Scanner.ReportProgress(CInt(totalRead_size / file_bytes_size) * 100)
                check_bgWorkerCancelled()
            Loop Until lineInFile Is Nothing
        End If

' clean temporary storage after each file operation
        temp_hash_values.Clear() : Erase hashFile_lineParts : Erase file_bytes : file_bytes_size = 0 : lineInFile = Nothing : Erase lineBytes : lineBytes_size = Nothing

    End Sub
```

**Extra Code**

I'm also checking if the worker is cancelled on each loop cycle to make sure that when the toggle button is clicked, the worker does not keep running. The following is code for check function:

```
' Method: To check is cancellation is pending
    Private Sub check_bgWorkerCancelled()
        ' check if cancellation is pending
        If bgWorker_Scanner.CancellationPending = True Then
            ' background worker cancel asynchronoous operating
            If bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then
                bgWorker_Scanner.CancelAsync()
            End If
            isScanning = False
            Try
                ' invoke to bypass illegal cross threading UI update
                BeginInvoke(CType(Sub()
                                      progressBar1.Value = 0
                                      txtStatus.Text = "Cancelled"
                                      txtCalmDown.Text = ""
                                      btnToggleScan.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "/res/malware_scanner/rocket.png")
                                  End Sub, MethodInvoker))
            Catch ex As Exception : End Try
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

Can't seem to figure out why it's not kicking in. Any help is appreciated.
Here is a screenshot for more details: [image: Runtime Image]

Comment: I think you meant for this: `If bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then` to be like this: `If Not bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then`. The former will only run the BGW if it is _already running_.

Comment: `CInt(totalRead_size / file_bytes_size) * 100` should be `CInt(totalRead_size * 100 / file_bytes_size)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Did not notice it. This solved the problem.

Comment: Rather than putting 'Solved' in the title, mark an answer as the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant for this: If bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then to be like this: If Not bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then. The former will only run the BGW if it is already running. 
**– Visual Vincent**

This solved the main issue of worker no running

CInt(totalRead_size / file_bytes_size) * 100 should be CInt(totalRead_size * 100 / file_bytes_size)
**– Andrew Morton**

This solved the issue of progressbar.

Thanks a lot!